# Toggle multiple divs while showing only one div, possibility a jquery accordion?

Tags: jquery, toggle, jquery-animate, jquery-ui-accordion

Currently when the user clicks on the link, the `$('#user');` slides out. When the user clicks on another (NOT THE SAME LINK) `$('.more-info-arrow').find('a')` link, the user's information from the previous goes away but does not reappear with the second request. I would like this to do this only if the `$('#user');` is visible.

http://jsfiddle.net/QSapW/

=======================Jquery====================

```
            //User detail information
        $('.more-info-arrow').find('a').live('click', function () {
            var $this = $(this);
            var user = $('#user');
            var userInfo = $('#user-info');

            // If display is none, that means it is hidden
            if (user.css('display') == 'none') {
                $this.addClass('active');
                user.hide().animate({
                    width: 'toggle'
                }, 400, function () {
                    userInfo.fadeIn('fast');
                });
            }

            // Second Click
            else {
                $this.removeClass('active');
                userInfo.fadeOut('fast', function () {
                    user.animate({
                        width: 'toggle'
                    }, 400);
                });
            }
        });
```

[image: phone book web app]

Comment: What exactly would you like to happen only if the `$('#user');` is visible? I tried your demo on Chrome and Firefox. The `$('#user')` toggles in and out just find when you click on either link... but I'm guessing that's *not* what you want.

Comment: Correct. Say if the user clicks on one link and then clicks on the another link, I would like the second reappearance of $('#user'); to show again.

Comment: Understand this... there will be more than 2 links with the same class '$('.more-info-arrow').find('a')', I just give that as an explain.

Comment: But you only have 1 `#user`. If I'm understanding you correctly, you want another box just like `#user` to show up?

Comment: Yes, the id may change when the **$('.more-info-arrow').find('a')** is clicked

Comment: Is it possible to give the **#user** a different id each time the **$('.more-info-arrow').find('a')** is clicked?

Comment: Any idea? By the way, thank you for helping me.

Answer (score 1):

If you're using HTML5, you can take advantage of the new `data` attributes.

Demo here: http://jsfiddle.net/QSapW/4/

**HTML**

```
<div class="item-info clearfix" data-userId="1">
    <div class="more-info-arrow"><a title="" href="javascript:;">&gt;&gt;</a></div>
</div>
<div class="item-info clearfix" data-userId="2">
    <div class="more-info-arrow"><a title="" href="javascript:;">&gt;&gt;</a></div>
</div>

<div class="user" id="user-box-1">
    <div class="user-info">
        <p>hello world</p>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="user" id="user-box-2">
    <div class="user-info">
        <p>good-bye world</p>
    </div>
</div>​
```

**JS**

```
//User detail information
$('.more-info-arrow').on('click', 'a', function () {
    var $this    = $(this),
        $item    = $this.parents('.item-info'),
        userId   = $item.data('userid'),
        user     = $('#user-box-' + userId),
        userInfo = $('.user-info', user);

    // If display is none, that means it is hidden
    if (user.is(':visible') === false) {
        $this.addClass('active');
        user.animate({
            width: 'toggle'
        }, 400, function () {
            userInfo.fadeIn('fast');
        });
    }

    // Second Click
    else {
        $this.removeClass('active');
        userInfo.fadeOut('fast', function () {
            user.animate({
                width: 'toggle'
            }, 400);
        });
    }
});​
```

**CSS**

```
.user {
    display:none;
    width:100px;
    height:100px;
    background:red;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. It's not working and I see why... I'll submit a jsfiddle just in a bit.

Comment: It's my fault... http://jsfiddle.net/QSapW/3/ The $('.user') is outside the <div class="item-info clearfix">, not inside.

Comment: The problem is that there has to be a way to tie an `.item-info` with a `.user`. Are all the `user` objects always going to be the identical?

Comment: The class can be identical, but user id will change.

Comment: I see what your saying though.

Comment: Alright... help me help you. Give me some more context here man. I don't even know what you're trying to do. I can only go on the markup you provided. What else can you bring to the table to tie `.item-info` with a `.user`.

Comment: Ok, I'll explain what I'm trying to do.. Currently I'm working on a phonebook web app. The '.item-info' wraps around the preview information of each user's information such as Name, Title, number, and email. If the user that's searching sees the user in the search results, they have the option to click on the '.more-info-arrow a' button to view more information. After clicking '.more-info-arrow a' on the particular user, the '.user' is triggered that will display more information (SEE PICTURE ABOVE).

Comment: I uploaded a picture for better understanding.

Comment: Are all the user details going to be loaded with the page or will you load them one-by-one via AJAX? Does every entry have a unique ID we can use?

Comment: The user details will load with the page. Every entry will have a unique ID. Not sure what the unique IDs will be yet.